# Show Custom Field of Current Page in For Loop

Tags: custom-field

I'm implementing a scrolling horizontal template and this is the code to divs that are the pages of the template.

```
 <?php for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++) { ?>
<div class="container" id="page-<?php echo $i ?>">
    <div class="left278">
        <?php 
            $specialPosts = new WP_Query();
            $specialPosts->query('pagename=page-'.$i.'');

            $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('custom_select');
                foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
                    if ($value='one') { 
                       include 'templates/slideshow-template.php'; }
                    else if ($value=='two') { 
                       include 'templates/full-page.php'; 
                }  ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see I get the page name, and I have a custom field where you can choose the template page.

The problem is that it get always the custom field value of the first page. So if i choose option one in the first page and option two in the second page it shows always the first template.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the $post->ID to the function or setting up the current post via a call to 
$specialPosts->the_post() that fills it for you

See [get_post_custom_values](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) documentation in the codex or this [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) on how to use it.

Try

```
<?php 
            $specialPosts = new WP_Query();
            $specialPosts->query('pagename=page-'.$i.'');

            while($specialPosts->have_posts()): $specialPosts->the_post();

               $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('custom_select');
                   foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {

            ...
            endwhile;
```